# How can I stop the Inspect Element Tab from constantly reloading the page with Netbeans Connector

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, netbeans, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the Netbeans Connector (a chrome plugin) in addition to the Chrome Developer Tools to make adjustments to my css styles, which is quite effective, except that the page refreshes every few seconds, and anything I'm typing at the time is lost.

The box at the bottom of the page says "Waiting for ajax.googleapis.com". Now I am using the google hosted version of JQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However I don't see why that would cause the page to refresh like this and lose all my data.
Any ideas?

Comment: I would say this is a question for the Netbeans Connector plugin writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on project in Projects window in NetBeans, select Project Properties and now it depends on type of your project:

- for PHP, select Browsers category and uncheck "Reload browser on save"
- for HTML5, select Run category and uncheck "Auto-refresh"
- for Java Web/Maven Web project, there will be similar option